# In Google Analytics, how can I plot an overtime line chart of the percentage of visitors from mobile devices out of total number of visitors?

Tags: google-analytics

how can I plot this metric? Note that I want to see a graph of the percentage of mobile devices visitors out of the total number of visitors, but **without** also displaying the total number of visitors on the same graph.

(BTW it can be also visits, not visitors)

Comment: I deleted my answer because I can't see how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to get the graph you want in Google Analytics.   It is hidden under "motion charts".

1. Select your date range
2. Navigate to "Audience" -> "Mobile" -> "Overview"
3. Select "Motion charts" (it is an icon with three bubbles over the graph on the right)
4. Select "Sessions" from the sideways select menu to the left of the graph (the default "% of new sessions" tells you how much of your mobile traffic is returning visitors)
5. Select "Line chart" from the tabs that appear above the graph (as opposed to the line chart icon next to the motion charts icon).

Here is the graph from one of my sites.  The green line is mobile and it is clearly growing.

[image: mobile usage over time in Google Analytics]

Comment: I know, old answer. But these are still absolute values, not percentages. The exact same graph is available in the normal "Line Chart" view, by checking off the three device categories and clicking the "Plot Rows" button.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this directly within Google Analytics, but if you view both segments as suggested by mmarschall, then you can export the data to CSV and draw your graph in Excel (or similar).

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Advanced Segments" in any report and check "All Visits" and "Mobile Traffic". After hitting apply you'll see both graphs (e.g. visits) in your report.

Comment: That lets you see the average percentage of mobile traffic for the period you've chosen, but not a graph with the percentage plotted over time.

Answer (score 0):

Irreverent but honest answer (to my knowledge): Sometimes you gotta pick up pencil, paper, and calculator.

I realize there may be a systematic way to do certain things but if the time involved in figuring it out is extensive and I can readily calculate it, I go old school.